# How to change handle Light System Bars navigation theme to API 30 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm looking for the latest update to change the

```
`fun handleLightSystemBars(view: View) {
    view.systemUiVisibility =  if (isThemeNight()) 0 else View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
} `
```

To API 30 in Android Studio Kotlin programming:

```
@JvmStatic
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)

fun handleLightSystemBars(view: View) {
    view.systemUiVisibility =
        if (isThemeNight()) 0 else View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
}
```

Does somebody know how to help?